# Wordpress redirection regex: match on two strings and return query params

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

I'm using the Wordpress redirection plugin and trying to match a URL based on the presence of two strings, and then return all the query params for use in the redirect URL. Here's the gist of what I'm trying to do:

Source URL: https://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?q=some/abc/value&reset=1&m=xyz
Match on the presence of two strings: wp-admin and some/abc/value
Grab the query string for use in the redirect URL
Redirect URL: https://example.com/mynewpath/?q=some/abc/value&reset=1&m=xyz

I can come up with the regex for the matching piece: `^.*?\bwp-admin\b.*?\some\/abc\/value\b.*?$` -- but I'm stuck figuring out how to then retrieve the query string for use in the redirection URL.

Comment: Did the answer work out?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 capturing groups

```
^(https?:\/\/\S*?\/)wp-admin\b\S*?(\?q=some\/abc\/value\b.*)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ghi1FA/1)

In the replacement use the 2 capturing groups, denoted by `$1` and `$2`

```
$1mynewpath/$2
```

*In parts*

- `^`  Start of string
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `https?:\/\/\S*?\/` Match the protocol with optional `s` and `://` followed by as least as possible chars and `/`
- `)` Close group 1
- `wp-admin\b\S*?` Match `wp-admin` followed by as least as possible non whitespace chars *(This is the part that you don't want to keep)*
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `\?q=some\/abc\/value\b.*` Match `?` and the querystring params
- `)` Close group 2
- `$` End of string